# Can I display select array data in a Freeform notification template?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a form that contains an array field, e.g. `name="product_list[]"`. Is there anyway to access specific values within this array in the notification template? All I'm currently doing is adding `{product_list}` which barfs them all out in a line. Is there a way to print only value 1, only value 2, etc?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of field are you storing these in?

If you are using Freeform Pro and a Multi-select field, it supports a tag pair for the selected data:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#multi-select_attr_name

If its a standard textarea field and you are just using the array input, its going to store it as regular text with no way by default to split it on output. It's going to come out as if it was all written at once in the textarea.

However, Notifications are ran as full templates as of Freeform 4 and you could use something along the lines of the PHPStringFun addon to explode the string output: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun